# meta.so stuck on mobile

Tags: support, meta, mobile-web

I was awarded a "yearling" badge on meta.so just now, while visiting the regular SO, but when I clicked on the notification, I was taken to the mobile view of meta.so.

I regularly visit from my phone, but right now, I'm using Firefox ESR on Windows 7 and the regular SO works as I expect. Visiting other sites in the SE network gets me their "full site" view.

(I do realize I could click "full site" in the footer and expect the problem to perhaps just go away, but I won't do that just yet, in case somebody wants to figure out what's wrong.)

Comment: Your rep on MSO is from the full site. That is a product of the MSO/MSE split.

Comment: You are on MSO, the new child Meta for Stack Overflow. You have no independent reputation here. Click on the 'full site' link in the footer to go back to the regular web view.

Comment: The old MSO was renamed to Meta Stack Exchange and [your account is still there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/169312/tripleee).

Comment: I am aware of the transition. I will remove the details about my profile and leave the main question, about the site being mobile even though the rest of the network knows I am not using a mobile browser right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the mobile view is the default for new visits from a mobile browser, you can always manually switch between the web and mobile views with a link in the site footer:

[image: to mobile]
[image: back again]

When you do this, the preference is stored in a cookie. Either you have clicked on 'mobile' in your desktop Firefox ESR browser at some point, or Firefox ESR synchronizes cookies between devices.

The cookie is *per site* (where child metas do get their own cookie); it is not a network-wide setting.

It is otherwise *not* a regular occurrence; personally I prefer the setting to work this way; making it work across the network would require storing the setting on the network profile, which I imagine will have its own synchronization nightmares..

Comment: I don't have Firefox on my phone, so Firefox cannot sync between these devices.  I have no recollection of visiting the mobile version of meta with Firefox, ever; but I guess I'll accept this as a possible explanation and move on.

Comment: Then the only remaining option is that you used the 'mobile' link at some point.

Comment: Thanks! This answer saved me when I accidentally got into mobile mode on a desktop (Firefox). However, going the ***other way***, choosing "mobile" now results in a ***"Page Not Found"*** error (I don't know if there is a meta post reporting this problem or not). This was observed on Stack Overflow proper, not meta.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I can't reproduce that. Perhaps you were on a page for which there is no mobile equivalent (not all pages have one)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I can't immediately think of a good example; the ones I know off are all moderator-only.

Comment: Yep, you are right. It is not a problem on most pages, but an example is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/today/hot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/today/hot). I am certain there are others, but I couldn't locate them.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: right, there is simply not a mobile version for that page; you couldn't navigate there from other mobile pages.